# Displaying all records from table in Azure Mobile Services Database in Windows 8 store app - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, windows-8, azure-mobile-services

This question can be summarised as: how do I display all the records in a table that have a particular ID? (I have the records displaying in the correct places, but they appear as something similar to Folder.Folder.List)

I've been trying to display all the records that contain a certain monthYearID field.

The page layout is a split page, and when you click on one of the items in the list view (which go from January from December), the second half of the screen should display all of the entries in the database from that month and year in another list view that I put in myself. (The user can select what year they want, which will make up the monthYearID in combination with the month they pick in the list view)

I have it so that correct entries are appearing when the appropriate months and years are selected, but instead of showing the record, it's showing the reference(?) to the record.

I only want the day, time and title fields of the records to be displayed, so this is what I have:

```
        private async void GetJournalEntries()
    {
        items = await JournalEntries.Where(journalEntries => journalEntries.MonthYearID == monthYearID).ToListAsync();

        List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

        for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            int x = items[i].Day;
            string a = x.ToString();
            string b = items[i].Time;
            string c = items[i].Title;

            list.Add(new Data(a, b, c));
        }

        //List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

        //List<journalEntries> result = items.FindAll(s => );

        //List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

        //Find a way of displaying just the date, time and entry title

        entryList.ItemsSource = list ;
    }
```

As you can see in the comments, I have a bunch of stuff left over from different things I've tried. The above block started as:

```
        private async void GetJournalEntries()
    {
        items = await JournalEntries.Where(journalEntries => journalEntries.MonthYearID == monthYearID).ToListAsync();

        //Find a way of displaying just the date, time and entry title

        entryList.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

and I know that my other team mate was able to

```
var currentUser = login.FirstOrDefault();
```

for whatever she was using, but this doesn't apply when there are multiple records that need to be displayed.

I just haven't been able to figure out what to use instead, and it's gotten to the point that we can't move on in our project - the deadline of which is tomorrow.

If I've left anything out, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The references are shown because you provide a list with complex objects (not simple strings).

1. In such cases you should declare an ItemTemplate where you specify which properties from the complex object should be used - in your case "Time" and "Title".

   ```
   <ItemsControl x:Name="entryList">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```
2. Another solution would be to provide as datasource a list of strings; here's how you can change the code which composes the list:

   ```
   List<String> list = new List<String>();

   for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
   {
       int x = items[i].Day;
       string a = x.ToString();
       string b = items[i].Time;
       string c = items[i].Title;

       //here whatever format you want..
       list.Add(a + " " + b + " " + c));
   }
   ```